# How to do Operator Overloading?

Tags: f#, operator-overloading

I did this :

```
let (-) (m:float[]) (n:float[])=  [| for i = 0 to Array.length m - 1 do yield m.[i]-n.[i] |]
```

But, why this is wrong?!

```
let y=1.0-0.0
```

That is ok before!

```
Error   1   This expression was expected to have type     float []     but here has type     float      E:\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\curve intersection\newton\Module1.fs 28  7   newton
Error   2   This expression was expected to have type     float []     but here has type     float      E:\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\curve intersection\newton\Module1.fs 28  11  newton
```

I think  (m:float[]) (n:float[]) is set the parameters type , why 1.0-0.0, float*float, not go to use (-) float*float->float???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You completely redefined the `-` operator.

If you want to augment one of your *own* types to work with `-`, you can do that (the builtin operator definitions will pick up members on a type).  But I don't think there's any way to define existing operators on builtin/existing types that doesn't completely shadow the builtin operator definition.

You can either use a local `let` binding to temporarily shadow `-` to work on float arrays, or you can define a new operator instead.  Examples:

```
// locally shadow
let f() =
    let (-) (a:float[]) (b:float[]) = ...
    // use (-) on arrays for a moment
// use (-) as normal
```

and

```
// new operator
let (-@) (a:float[]) (b:float[]) = ...
[|1.0|] -@ [|2.0|]  // my new op
1.0 - 2.0           // minus as normal
```

Comment: thanks, that is the reasion. why F# does not like C#, identify the parameters by types?

Comment: Because they are different languages?  There are a _lot_ of interactions going on here that I can't sum up in a comment.  Briefly, let-bound identifiers cannot be ad-hoc overloaded in F#.

Answer (score 1):

You added an operator overload for the type `float[]`.  In the sample code though you are trying to subject 2 `float` values which doesn't work.  Try the following

```
let y = [|1.0|] - [|0.0|]
```

The `[| ... |]` syntax is used to create an array of values.  In the above case it creates two `float[]` each with a single `float` value.

Comment: no,no. I what to do "1.0-0.0",not  [|1.0|] - [|0.0|]. It should be wrong?

Comment: That means your operator overloading is wrong. It should be `let (-) (m:float) (n:float) =`